# XDocument formatting elements

Tags: c#, .net

I have an issue with xdocument I keep getting this format:

```
<DB caption="001" rules="6">
    <RULES>
        <RULE data_type="2" option="0">
            <RULE data_type="2" option="0"/>
        </RULE>
    </RULE>
</DB>
```

Here is my code:

```
new XElement("DB",
new XAttribute("caption", "001"),
new XAttribute("rules","6"),
new XElement("RULE",
new XAttribute("data_type", "2"),
new XAttribute("option", "0"),
new XElement("RULE",
new XAttribute("data_types", "2"),
new XAttribute("option", "0")));
```

However I need the output to be in the following format:

```
<DB caption="001" rules="6">
    <RULES>
        <RULE data_type="2" option="0"/>
        <RULE data_type="2" option="0"/>
    </RULES>
</DB>
```

----Edit

I have also tried:

```
new XElement("DB",
new XAttribute("caption", "001"),
new XAttribute("rules","6"),
new XElement("RULE"),
new XAttribute("data_type", "2"),
new XAttribute("option", "0"),
new XElement("RULE"),
new XAttribute("data_types", "2"),
new XAttribute("option", "0"));
```

The above didn't work either.

Comment: just look at your closing parenthesis closely and you will see that you create the second RULE element inside the first one..

Comment: Hello, I have tried closing the parenthesis at "RULE" as well but format is still not correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's format your code to see what's happening:

```
new XElement("DB",
    new XAttribute("caption", "001"),
    new XAttribute("rules","6"),
    new XElement("RULE",
        new XAttribute("data_type", "2"),
        new XAttribute("option", "0"),
        new XElement("RULE",
            new XAttribute("data_types", "2"),
            new XAttribute("option", "0")));
```

You are creating the second 'RULE' element within the first one.  So, you have root element 'DB', which has a 'RULE' child, which has a 'RULE' child.

Try this instead:

```
new XElement("DB",
    new XAttribute("caption", "001"),
    new XAttribute("rules","6"),
    new XElement("RULE",
        new XAttribute("data_type", "2"),
        new XAttribute("option", "0")),
    new XElement("RULE",
        new XAttribute("data_type", "2"),
        new XAttribute("option", "0")));
```

Code readability goes a long way in solving bugs.

Comment: @RobertC No problem.